# TexInputLayout Error Messege not getting set

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout

I have used a TextInputLayout in my xml as :

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                            android:id="@+id/fname_label"
                             android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:theme="@style/TextLabel">

                            <com.app.sales_shfc.FontClass.Edittext_RobotoRegular
                                android:id="@+id/firstNameEt"
                                style="@style/editTextStylewhite"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                                android:maxLength="15" />

                        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

And have created a method for setting error to the textinputlayout,

```
public static void setErrorTextInputLayout(TextInputLayout textInputLayout, String errorMsg, boolean enableError) {
        textInputLayout.setErrorEnabled(enableError);
        if (enableError) {
               textInputLayout.setError(errorMsg);
        }

    }
```

I tried setting setError null but whenever my validation conditions are false it must  throw error

```
 if (presalesValidation.first_name && (firstNameEt.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0 || !Utility.isNameValid(firstNameEt.getText().toString().trim()) || firstNameEt.getText().toString().contains(" "))) {
            Utility.setErrorTextInputLayout(fname_label, "Please enter a proper first name", true);
            validate = false;
        } else {
            Utility.setErrorTextInputLayout(fname_label, "", false);
        }
```

Error comes for the first time but later it takes the space for the error but does not show the error messege.

```
<style name="MyAppTheme.TextInputLayout" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/errorRed</item>
    </style>
```

Here is the Theme :

```
<style name="TextLabel" parent="Widget.Design.TextInputLayout">
        <!-- Hint color and label color in FALSE state -->
        <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/secondaryColor</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundTint">@color/secondaryColor</item>
        <!-- Label color in TRUE state and bar color FALSE and TRUE State -->
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/secondaryColor</item>
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/secondaryColor</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/secondaryColor</item>
        <item name="errorTextAppearance">@style/MyAppTheme.TextInputLayout</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: `android:theme="@style/TextLabel"` share theme!

Comment: Edited the question please check.

Answer (score 0):

Try request Focus on the Same EditText after Seting error

```
public static void setErrorTextInputLayout(TextInputLayout textInputLayout, String errorMsg, boolean enableError) {
        textInputLayout.setErrorEnabled(enableError);
        if (enableError) {
               textInputLayout.setError(errorMsg);
               textInputLayout.requestFocus();
        }

    }
```

Comment: No this did not work actually error is getting set but text is not being displayed.

Comment: Can U add screenshot please